# R, Merge two datasets, splitting into multiple columns

Tags: r, left-join, tidyverse

I have two datasets:

```
    PeopleList<-structure(list(MRN = c("53634", "65708", "64320", "40458", "03935", 
"67473", "20281", "52479", "10261", "40945", "40630", "92295", 
"43505", "80719", "39492", "44720", "70691", "21351", "03457", 
"02182"), DOB = c("9/13/1953", "4/5/1948", "4/18/1944", "9/6/1953", 
"1/14/1957", "8/25/1952", "6/4/1967", "7/22/1988", "6/22/1947", 
"5/10/1957", "1/12/1968", "4/3/1979", "8/26/1961", "5/25/1965", 
"8/21/1955", "9/17/1936", "9/13/1965", "3/23/1942", "5/16/1992", 
"3/6/1969"), Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female"), `Smoking Status` = c("Never Smoker", "Former Smoker", 
"Never Smoker", "Never Smoker", "Former Smoker", "Former Smoker", 
"Never Smoker", "Never Smoker", "Former Smoker", "Never Smoker", 
"Never Smoker", "Former Smoker", "Never Smoker", "Former Smoker", 
"Former Smoker", "Former Smoker", "Never Smoker", "Never Smoker", 
"Never Smoker", "Never Smoker")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

Complications<-structure(list(MRN = c("03412", "25052", "64320", "64320", "64320", 
"47595", "47595", "45175", "45337", "93708", "03348", "12964", 
"12964", "46272", "46272", "46272", "46272", "71331", "57923", 
"57923"), `ENCOUNTER DIAGNOSES` = c("Rupture of implant of right breast, subsequent encounter [T85.43XD]; Rupture of implant of right breast, subsequent encounter [T85.43XD]; Rupture of implant of right breast, subsequent encounter [T85.43XD]", 
"Breast asymmetry [N64.89]; Rupture of implant of left breast, sequela [T85.43XS]; Rupture of implant of left breast, sequela [T85.43XS]; Rupture of implant of left breast, sequela [T85.43XS]", 
"Extrusion of breast implant, subsequent encounter [T85.49XD]; Extrusion of breast implant, subsequent encounter [T85.49XD]; Extrusion of breast implant, subsequent encounter [T85.49XD]", 
"Extrusion of breast implant, subsequent encounter [T85.49XD]; Extrusion of breast implant, subsequent encounter [T85.49XD]; Extrusion of breast implant, subsequent encounter [T85.49XD]", 
"Breast asymmetry [N64.89]", "Fat necrosis (segmental) of breast [N64.1]", 
"Fat necrosis (segmental) of breast [N64.1]", "Hematoma of breast [N64.89]", 
"Acquired breast deformity [N64.89]", "Capsular contracture of breast implant, sequela [T85.44XS]; Capsular contracture of breast implant, sequela [T85.44XS]; Capsular contracture of breast implant, sequela [T85.44XS]", 
"Infected sebaceous cyst [L72.3, L08.9]", "Pain due to any device, implant or graft, subsequent encounter [T85.848D]", 
"Pain due to any device, implant or graft, sequela [T85.848S]", 
"Breast asymmetry [N64.89]", "Breast asymmetry [N64.89]", "Breast asymmetry [N64.89]", 
"Breast asymmetry [N64.89]", "Acquired breast deformity [N64.89]", 
"Hematoma of breast [N64.89]", "Hematoma of breast [N64.89]")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

"Complications" is a data frame with thousands of people I may not necessarily care about.  "Peoplelist" is 500 or so people I do care about.  What I'd like to do is merge the info from "Complications" over into "PeopleList" by MRN's, only keeping the MRNs from "PeopleList".

That parts easy, I could do `PeopleList<-PeopleList%>%left_join(Complications,by="MRN")`

But the problem is I want to only merge over "Encounter Diagnoses" that aren't duplicates, and also if I have multiple matches for an MRN I want them split to multiple columns, not rows (there shouldn't be more than 5-6 new columns tops).   Here's what I mean:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
PeopleList%>%left_join(
  Complications %>% #pipework to have 1 row per MRN
    unique() %>% #drop duplicates
    group_by(MRN) %>%
    mutate(
      rank = row_number(), #rownumber per MRN
      rank = paste('Diagnosis', rank, sep = "_") #give this a tidier name
    ) %>%
    spread(rank, `ENCOUNTER DIAGNOSES`), #make this a 'wide' dataset rather than long
  by = "MRN" #join on
)
```